# Does order of alternatives in regex matters?

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract letters and numbers from a string.

I tried this:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[a-z]|\d*','a11b4')
['a', '11', 'b', '4', '']
>>> re.findall(r'\d*|[a-z]','a11b4')
['', '11', '', '4', '']
```

Why changing the order of alternatives in regex, changes the output?

Comment: ArturMD - See similar question as FYI... https://superuser.com/questions/1199574/powershell-regex-split-on-single-and-double-white-space

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're using `\d` with `*`.

When you have `[a-z]|\d*`, it'll first try to match `a-z`. If not, it'll try and match 0 or more repetitions of a digit. In your example, it'll match `a` first.

However, the other way around, it'll first try and match 0 or more repetitions of a digit. Well, `a` ***is*** 0 repetitions of a digit, so it qualifies as a 'match'. It won't try to evaluate the `[a-z]` expression, as it already qualified for 0 repetitions.

In order to use this pattern properly (especially if it *has* to be a letter or  at least one digit), you could instead use:

`[a-z]|\d+` or `\d+|[a-z]`

This would look for 1 or more repetitions of a digit, fail to match on `a`, and then evaluate `[a-z]`, resulting in the response you expected.